# No results returns while using 'where' clause in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using a simple select object to list all the parent categories as follows.

```
$select = $this->sql->select();
$select -> where(array('cat_parent_id'=>2));
$statement = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$result = $statement->execute();
```

When I run the above code, I donot have an error message but I always have a null result. If I use the where clause without the array params then I have the good results. 
    $select -> where('cat_parent_id=2');

To learn more, I tried to get the sql string using the code below, 
    $select = $this->sql->select();
    $select -> where(array('cat_parent_id'=>2));
    $sqlstring = $this->sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);

I have a warning.

> Notice: Attempting to quote a value in Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql without extension/driver support can introduce security vulnerabilities in a production environment. in D:\wamp\www\shops\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql.php on line 128

I really would like to use the array method inside the where clause. Any help would be very appreciated. :)

Comment: You can pass an array to the select function

Comment: Hi Aydin, can you please give an example in my above code.  Thank you Laxman

Comment: Something like : `$select = $this->sql->select(array('cat_parent_id'=>2));`

Comment: hi, it seems to work now. thank you all for the help. I still do not know what caused the problem...